# Fill a google chart with data from a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This seems to be something very simple but I have searched and not found a solution. I am trying to create a chart on my site based on the data in a google spreadsheet. I have been able to get it working using hard coded values but not sure how to fill from a spreadsheet.

My current script looks like this:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

My data on my spread sheet is simlilar to what is hard coded but I want to give it the spreadsheet url and have it fill it from that (url like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnD0SFr9ooPgdG83Wm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a tutorial with an example here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets

Basically, you code will look like: (I'm not sure your URL is correct. Also, set the end of the url to use the right range of data):

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

function initialize() {
        var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
        // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AnD0SFr9ooPgdG83Wm&transpose=0&headers=1&merge=COLS&range=A1%3AA5%2CB1%3AC5&gid=0&pub=1', opts);         
        -
        // Optional request to return only column C and the sum of column B, grouped by C members.
        //query.setQuery('select C, sum(B) group by C');

        // Send the query with a callback function.
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
      
      google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: What's meaning the `-` after the`var query` declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way

```
/* Google sheet dynamic data */

function drowChartUsingSheet(){
    var sheetUrl = 'your google sheet link here';
    var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(sheetUrl,opts);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}


/* handler function & drow chart */
function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_googlechart'));
    chart.draw(data,options);
}
```